# Eclipse Che failing to open file on restart

Tags: cakephp, eclipse-che

I have started using Eclipse che to develop a app using CakePHP. However when I exit and come back to the project it comes up with an error

```
The file app/config/database.php could not be opened
```

and i can no longer see the file in the directory structure. Creating a file of the same name does not produce an error.

All this file contains is a class with an array containing the infromation about connecting to a database eg ip, username and password.

Comment: I have never used Eclipse che. Try Netbeans

Comment: Eclipse che is the cloud based version of eclipse. There is not a cloud based version of Netbeans that I know of.